# facebook messenger og:image cropping

Tags: html, facebook

I have some issues with my website image preview when I share my website as private message on Facebook (in messenger not Facebook post). In my html homepage I use `og:image` and I tested with two different image (obviously not in the same time) size 200x200 and 600x315 (I also try by specify the width and height with `og:image:width` and `og:image:height` but nothing change).

When I share the website link (with 200x200 image) on facebook messenger (as private message in chat to a friend) I obtain on desktop a preview (in the small chat on bottom or directly in messenger) with my website description on the right and my website image not cropped on the left and this is correct due to using an image small than 600x315. On messenger mobile instead I see the image cropped on top and the description on bottom and this bad.

Then I try, as recommend by facebook, to use an image 600x315 and in this case the result got worse because on desktop I see in the small chat the website description on the right and the image cropped on the left and If I open messenger I see a large image not cropped on top and the description on bottom. On messenger mobile instead I see the image cropped on top and the description on bottom.